# How Do I Override Tailwind Base With SASS/SCSS

Tags: sass, gatsby, postcss, tailwind-css

## My Issue

My h3 font-weight override doesn't appear to work.

```
@tailwind base;

h3{
    @apply font-thin;
}

@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


h3{
    @apply font-thin;
}
```

As you can see in the image, the layout.css coming from Tailwind takes precedence over my styles.scss

[image]

## Some more background:

- Gatsby project with PostCSS and SASS plugin (I've copied the relevant gatsby-config.js here:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
      `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
        options: {
          postCssPlugins: [
            require("tailwindcss"),
            require("./tailwind.config.js"), // Optional: Load custom Tailwind CSS configuration
          ],
        }
      },
    ],
  }
```

Comment: Going through the Tailwind documentation, not sure where I'm going wrong here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#extending-preflight

Answer (score 1):

Oh I figured out the issue, layout.css isn't from Tailwinds ... it's boilerplate from Gatsby starter theme.

Found it and removed it from src/components/layout.js